# Somewhere nearby

Tags: visual

Make sense of what you see below and then tell me the message I'm looking for.

---

[image]

[image]

---

**What is this message?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The puzzle's arrows are referring to the

> upvote and downvote buttons on stack exchange sites. When the post is not your own, there are 3 possible states: upvoted, downvoted, or neither. Your own posts will not have a highlighted arrow. If you try to upvote or downvote your own post, you get this message:
>
>
>  [image]